# Asterisk astdb File increases size!

Tags: asterisk

I am using asterisk 1.2.37 with FreePBX 2.6.0 and i am having an issue that I am not quit understanding.
The Asterisk database file `/var/lib/asterisk/astdb` increases his size exponentially at least 1M per day. I am not understanding why. The calls are made automatically and in predictive mode as well. 
The increase happens only with the asterisk that make more automatic calls then predictive one, I am not quite familiar with Asterisk and I am trying to figure it out why this file have to be increased if it have the store of the extensions,

Any suggestion about this situation or if someone had any kind of problem like this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are no way answer your question "why" without info about your dialling system(very likly it just buggy)

You can check asterisk database content by

```
asterisk -rx "database show"
```

Note, use of asterisk 1.2 accessable via internet is extreamly bad idea. Hope you not allow access.

Comment: Actually i saw that the database takes too much to finish the command (about 30 sec) and all the calls are automatic,
here is an example:
`/UID23100012/channel                              : SIP/6322384-095f78f8     
/UID23100012/status                               : "NO ANSWER"              
/UID23100013/channel                              : SIP/6320541-09bc2330     
/UID23100013/channelagent                         : SIP/6320541-09bc2330     `
So every status is stored on the DB, can't understand this, maybe I am missing some config.

Answer (score 0):

FreePBX never compacts the free space in the astdb.  You can add a manual sqlite3 script / cron job that compacts the AstDB every nite.  For example:

```
sqlite3 /var/lib/asterisk/astdb.sqlite3 "VACUUM;"
```

Just one of the many "interesting" things about FreePBX.